# Remove duplicate records from table and return 3 columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm having an issue and I would like to return a table with one row per ticket ID.

SQL Query

```
SELECT
    tickets.tid,
    CASE WHEN ticketnotes.message 
            LIKE '%https://xxxx.zendesk.net/.../%' 
            THEN ticketnotes.message 
            ELSE '-' END as escalated,
    CASE WHEN ticketnotes.message 
            LIKE '%Ticket ID%Issue Summary%Suggested Solution%' 
            THEN ticketnotes.message 
            ELSE '-' END as message
FROM
    tickets
    INNER JOIN ticketnotes ON ticketnotes.ticketid = tickets.id
WHERE
    tickets.status = 'Closed' 
    AND tickets.did = 7
    AND DATE(tickets.date) BETWEEN DATE('2020-04-01') AND DATE('2020-04-30')
```

Output

[image: table]

The goal is to return a table with unique ticket ids and if there is a message or escalated message in ticket id, return it in column. If there is not, return a `-`.
The correct output if a ticket id got escalated and message, to be in one row with 3 column as shown in picture.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What i a ticket has 5, or 10 messages?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @zouaoui-zandeh one row with ticket id / escalated msg / message for every ticket. If more noted with links or “issue summary” another row of the ticket id.

Comment: @GMB if more notes, then more rows then. But should be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    distinct t1.tid,
    t2.message as "escalated",
    t3.message as "message"
FROM
    tickets t1
    left join (select ticketid, message from ticketnotes where message LIKE '%https://xxxx.zendesk.net/.../%') t2 on t2.ticketid = t1.tid 
    left join (select ticketid, message from ticketnotes where message LIKE '%Ticket ID%Issue Summary%Suggested Solution%') t3 on t3.ticketid = t1.tid 
WHERE
    t1.status = 'Closed' 
    AND t1.did = 7
    AND DATE(t1.date) BETWEEN DATE('2020-04-01') AND DATE('2020-04-30')
```